# MultiValueDictKeyError

Tags: django

I have the following code. The first works, however the second throws a "MultiValueDictKeyError". I've tweaked the code around a bit but I haven't been able to fix it. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

## Working Code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block base_content %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/themes/txt/css/employee_summary/report.css" />

<form id="myForm" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class=box>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="2u">
                    <h1>{{ field.label_tag }}:</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="10u">
                    {{ field }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

{% for formset in inlines %}
    <div class=box>        
        {% for form in formset %} 
            <div class="row">
                <div class="12u">
                    <h1>{{ form }}</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>     
{% endfor %}

{% for formset in inlines %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
{% endfor %}

    <input type="submit" value="Save Changes">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

## Non-Working Code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block base_content %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/themes/txt/css/employee_summary/report.css" />

<div id="main-wrapper">
<div class="strongborder">
    <div id="main" class="container boldtext">
        <form id="myForm" method="post" class="12u">
            {% csrf_token %}
                {% for field in form %}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="2u">
                            <h1>{{ field.label_tag }}:</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="10u">
                            {{ field }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}

            {% for formset in inlines %}
                {% for form in formset %}
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <h1>{{ form.instance.form_name }}</h1>
                    {% for field in form %}
                        <div class="row">
                            {% if field.label != "Employee" and field.label != "Id" and field.label != "Delete" %}
                                <label class="2u">{{ field.label }}:</label> 
                                <div class="10u">{{ field }}</div>
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}

        {% for formset in inlines %}
            {{ formset.management_form }}
        {% endfor %}

        <br>
        <br>

            <input type="submit" value="Save Changes">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Have the traceback? Where is the error occurring, and did you mean `MultiValueDictKeyError`?

Comment: Just added the exception value, and yes, I did mean MultiValueDictKeyError

Comment: Solved the problem! For some reason it doesn't like me excluding ID from the formset fields, but it allows me to skip the employee and delete fields. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Solved by myself: for some reason it wasn't liking the ID skip in

```
{% if field.label != "Employee" and field.label != "Id" and field.label != "Delete" %}
```

... yet it was fine with skipping the employee and delete fields.